# Custom 404 page in CakePHP 3.X

Tags: cakephp

I want to create one custom 404 page for all errors coming to the website for production environment. For example if I receive missing controller or view error then it will redirect to 
`http://example.com/404.html,` Also in some cases I will deliberately redirect it `http://example.com/404.html`

Earlier in CakePHP 2.x it was done by adding following action in AppContoller.php

```
public function appError($error) {
    $this->redirect('/page-not-found.html',301,false);
}
```

But It is not working in CakePHP 3.x, I want to replicate same behavior in CakePHP 3.x

Comment: You should not redirect user when there is a `404` error, you should simply [customize the template](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#exception-renderer) of the default `404`.

Comment: True, but in some cases when user changed the url manually within the domain I have to redirect that user to 404 page

Comment: What do  you mean by "when the user changed the url manually"? If the user enter a non-correct url, then cake will throw an error and display a 404 error, you should not have to redirect them to a custom page.

Comment: Lets say I have one url structure http://www.example.com/blogs/24 where blogs is a directory and 24 is the id of blog, and I am using this id for database query. Now if some user changed (this ID)it in the browser and query results in empty data, in that case I want to redirect user to custom 404 page

Comment: If it happens, you should throw a `Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException` instead of redirecting, if well configured this will render a 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

### Do not redirect

The correct action to take if a page should render a 404 is *to render a 404*.

Redirecting to another page is confusing for users, especially since many browsers cache 301 responses making the original url inaccessible. This also affects e.g. search engines as the static file `404.html` will have a 200 response code (unless you modify your webserver config) so it'll say 404 but simply not be.

[The blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html), which all devs should do before starting a project, guides you in the right direction:

```
public function view($id)
{
    $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
    $this->set(compact('article'));
}
```

The table method [get](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-single-entity-by-primary-key) returns a single entity object **or throws an exception**:

> If the get operation does not find any results a Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException will be raised. You can either catch this exception yourself, or allow CakePHP to convert it into a 404 error.

The controller code in this example doesn't need to have any "what if it doesn't exist" handling because *by default* if the record doesn't exist the result is a 404.

### Changing the 404 template

If you want to change the way the 404 or 500 pages look [change the template files](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#exception-renderer)

> For all 4xx and 5xx errors the template files error400.ctp and error500.ctp are used respectively.

The error template is [in your application](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Template/Error/error400.ctp), note that in production mode [the output is very minimal](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Template/Error/error400.ctp#L34-L41).

Answer (score 0):

If the get operation does not find any results a `Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException` will be raised. You can either catch this exception yourself, or allow CakePHP to convert it into a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way can be just implemented in two steps,

Step 1:

turn the debug mode off in config/app.php

Step 2:

Replace the content of  `src/Template/Layout/error.ctp` with your custom layout.