# How to handle unknown URL request in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP 3.3

I want to redirect all unknown URLs to login page, i.e. when someone types wrong URL they should be redirected to the login page and not show the usual error messages like below. Can anyone please guide me how to achieve this.

```
Missing Controller
Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException

Error: Unknown_urlController could not be found.

Error: Create the class Unknown_urlController below in file: src/Controller/Unknown_urlController.php


<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class Unknown_urlController extends AppController
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a bad idea to redirect your users instead of showing a 404 page. It might be best to show a custom 404 page with helpful information like a link to the login page.

[Similar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908093/711401)

### Changing the 404 template

If you want to change the way the 404 or 500 pages look [change the template files](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#exception-renderer)

> For all 4xx and 5xx errors the template files error400.ctp and error500.ctp are used respectively.

The error template is [in your application](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Template/Error/error400.ctp), note that in production mode [the output is very minimal](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Template/Error/error400.ctp#L34-L41).